# ¿Como obtener el valor de un Html.DropDownList para pasar su valor como parametro a una vista parcial en MVC asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Tengo el siguiente dropdownlist, que muestro los valores 5,10 y 15:

```
<%     Dim listItems = New List(Of ListItem) From { _
        New ListItem() With { _
            .Text = "5", _
            .Value = 5 _
        }, _
        New ListItem() With { _
            .Text = "10", _
            .Value = 10 _
        }, _
        New ListItem() With { _
            .Text = "15", _
            .Value = 15 _
        } _
    }
%>
<%: Html.DropDownList("listado_noticia_length", New SelectList(listItems, "Value", "Text"), New With {Key .[class] = "form-control estilo_dropdownlist input-sm", Key .[onchange] = "javascript:registro_mostrar();"})%>
```

pero necesito pasar el valor seleccionado del DropDownList (en este caso su id sería listado_noticia_length) a un parametro de esta vista parcial, específicamente a la variable cant_filas:

```
<%: Html.Action("partialListadoNoticia", "Noticias", New With {.pag = 1, .cant_filas = recibir el valor del dropdownlist listado_noticia_length ¿como?})%>
```

No se como le enviaría el valor del dropdownlist como parametro a una variable de la vista parcial. Sintacticamente no lo se. Necesito referenciar al valor de dropdownlist, como por ejemplo 
    <%:Dim valor_dropdownlist_seleccionado= listado_noticia_length.selectValue%>

Sería eso mi pregunta. Desde ya gracias.

Comment: El valor seleccionado cuando cargas la pantalla va a ser siempre 5 (el primero) ya que al crear el DropDownList no especificas ningún item seleccionado. ¿Qué tratas de hacer exactamente? ¿Cómo tienes definidas tus acciones?

Comment: si, siempre va a ser 5, pero no quiero pasar a .cant_filas el 5 en duro, sino que este referenciando el item seleccionado del dropdownlist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No vas a poder pasarle el valor del control porque en el momento que lo necesitas este aun ni siquiera se renderizo, es mas al definir el `Html.Action()` es codigo del lado del servidor, el dropdownlist como control aun no existe

Lo que podrias hacer es tomar el valor de la lista de items

```
<%: Html.Action("partialListadoNoticia", "Noticias", New With {.pag = 1, .cant_filas = listItems[0].Value })%>
```

como veras usando `listItems[0].Value` no dejas fijo el valor y lo tomas de la misma fuente que generar al dropdownlist

Comment: excelente, eres un genio @Leandro Tuttini